# Сортировка массива php

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив

```
$arr
```

у него несколько ключей
`$arr['c']`
и
`$arr['m']`
в них разные значения, мне нужно отсортировать по убыванию массив `$arr['c']`
то есть если

```
$arr['c'] = 0, $arr['m'] = 1
$arr['c'] = 0, $arr['m'] = 2
$arr['c'] = 7, $arr['m'] = 3
$arr['c'] = 2, $arr['m'] = 4
```

то будет

```
$arr['c'] = 7, $arr['m'] = 3
$arr['c'] = 2, $arr['m'] = 4
$arr['c'] = 0, $arr['m'] = 1
$arr['c'] = 0, $arr['m'] = 2
```

Код записи в массив

`foreach ($result2 as $key2 => $value2) {
    $arr[] = ['m'=>$value['manufacturer_id'],'c'=>$value2["COUNT(`product_id`)"]];
    }`

`print_r($arr)`

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [m] => 1 [c] => 7 ) ) 
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [m] => 2 [c] => 0 ) ) 
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [m] => 3 [c] => 0 ) ) 
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [m] => 4 [c] => 0 ) )
Array (
[0] => Array ( [m] => 5 [c] => 13 ) ) 
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [m] => 6 [c] => 1 ) ) 
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [m] => 7 [c] => 7 ) )
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61660/discussion-on-question-by-----php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лично я использую функцию [usort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php). Ей передаем массив и анонимную функцию сортировки.

```
$arr = array(
    array('c' => 7, 'm' => 1),
    array('c' => 0, 'm' => 2),
    array('c' => 0, 'm' => 3),
    array('c' => 0, 'm' => 4),
    array('c' => 13, 'm' => 5),
    array('c' => 1, 'm' => 6),
    array('c' => 7, 'm' => 7),
);

usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['c'] < $b['c'];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код в исправленном виде:

```
    foreach ($result_two as $key_two => $value_two) { 
        $arr['c'][] = $value_two["COUNT(product_id)"];
        $arr['m'][] = $value['manufacturer_id']; 
    }  

    for($i=0; $i<count($arr['c']); $i++){
        for($j=$i+1; $j<count($arr['c']); $j++){
            if($arr['c'][$i]<$arr['c'][$j]){
                $tempC = $arr['c'][$j];
                $tempM = $arr['m'][$j];
                $arr['c'][$j] = $arr['c'][$i];
                $arr['m'][$j] = $arr['m'][$i];
                $arr['c'][$i] = $tempC;
                $arr['m'][$i] = $tempM;
            }
        }
    }

    print_r($arr);
```

На выходе $arr:

```
    $arr['c'][] = 7; $arr['m'][] = 3;
    $arr['c'][] = 2; $arr['m'][] = 4;
    $arr['c'][] = 0; $arr['m'][] = 1;
    $arr['c'][] = 0; $arr['m'][] = 2;
```

Массив ДО, из PHPStorm:

```
Array
(
    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 2
        )

    [m] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

)
```

Массив ПОСЛЕ, из PHPStorm:

```
Array
(
    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
        )

    [m] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: `Array ( [c] => 7 [m] => 1 ) Array ( [c] => 0 [m] => 2 ) Array ( [c] => 0 [m] => 3 ) Array ( [c] => 0 [m] => 4 ) Array ( [c] => 13 [m] => 5 )`
Вот результат, сортировка так же по `m`

Comment: сортировка пузырьком — это возможно и здорово, но на этом ресурсе приветствуются практические решения, т.е. такие, которые можно применить на практике в реальном коде

Comment: @mymedia а вы скопируйте и вставьте этот код, и увидите что он работает!

Comment: @Daniil не обижайтесь, но сортировку пузырьком можно применять только в старших классах школы, либо на первых курсах вуза, когда их изучают. На практике их никто не использует, только в учебных целях.

Comment: @teran, в тако случаи, помогите товарищу, не томите

Comment: @Daniil вы излишне усложняете. не надо там иметь два массива `$arr['c']` и `$arr['m']`, нужен один массив, где элементами являются пары `[ 'm' => ... , 'c' => ... ]`, тогда и сортироваться он будет элементарно с `usort`

Comment: @teran я не усложняю, и не надумываю! я ответил на вопрос который задали!

Comment: мы оба додумываем, только по разному. у человека ошибочно написано `$arr['m'] = ...` вы додумываете в сторону `$arr['m'][]`  а я `$arr[] = ['m' => ..., ]`. но в представленном виде `print_r` фигурируют именно пары значений `m,c`, поэтому моя додумка более вероятно окажется корректной.

Comment: @teran вывод с вашей версией `Array ( [0] => Array ( [c] => 7 ) [1] => Array ( [m] => 1 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [c] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [m] => 2 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [c] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [m] => 3 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [c] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [m] => 4 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [c] => 13 ) [1] => Array ( [m] => 5 ) )`

Comment: @Daniil И ничего не изменилось `Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => 7 ) [m] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) ) Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [m] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ) Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [m] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) ) Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [m] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) ) Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => 13 ) [m] => Array ( [0] => 5 ) )`

Comment: @МолюскаМоллюсков, вот я не поленился и дебажил кусок кода, который написал. Ну ведь то как вы ставите задачу, это ответ на вопрос. Если вы хотите что-то другое, нужно было выражатсья конкретнее

Comment: @Daniil вы показали в своей части выхода `$arr` именно то, что я хотел, но на деле ничего не сортируется

Comment: @МолюскаМоллюсков значит вы вносите любые изменения к тому что я написал, у меня работает а у вас нет? - это же смешно!

Comment: массив до `Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => 7 ) [m] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) ) Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [m] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ) Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [m] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) )  ` массив после `Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => 7 ) [m] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) ) Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [m] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ) Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [m] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) )`

Comment: @МолюскаМоллюсков Я предлагаю на этом остановиться, лично от меня вы можете получить ответ (другой), только в том случае, если поставите вопрос по-другому!

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле непонятно, зачем вы используете такую странную структуру данных для случая, когда элементы `m` и `c` являются связанными.

Я бы на вашем месте для начала преобразовал массив `['m'=>[values_m...],'c'=>[values_c...]]` к виду `[['m'=>value_m, 'c'=>value_c]...]`, а потом, когда необходимо, использовал `usort`

**PHP 7** Для 5 надо чуть поменять функцию сортировки в `usort`

```
$in = ['m'=>[values_m...],'c'=>[values_c...]];
$out = [];
for($i=0;$i<count($in['m']);$i++){
    $out[] = ['m'=>$in['m'][$i], 'c'=>$in['c'][$i]];
}
usort($out, function($a, $b){ return $a['c'] <=> $b['c']; });
```

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4575769b575b79e68b5bacac4baee808cbfbc8b3)

Comment: там в комментариях к вопросу есть код заполнения массива, с ошибкой. добавьте его в свой ответ, а то не поймет  (: я пытался объяснить, но что-то безуспешно

Comment: `foreach ($result_two as $key_two => $value_two) { $arr['c'] = $value_two["COUNT(\`product_id\`)"]; $arr['m'] = $value['manufacturer_id']; } `

Comment: @teran мммм. прям вот так? Там же в любом случае только 2 элемента будет в итоге :)

Comment: дак я и написал, что заполняется с ошибкой :) хотелось то `$arr[] = [ c => , m => ]` видимо. у меня не получилось это объяснить в комментах  :)

Comment: @teran да я так сделал, даже скидывал Вам массив после такой записи

Comment: @МолюскаМоллюсков  я ваш код привел, в нем ошибка (если в про второй коммент)

Comment: @teran `Array ( [0] => Array ( [c] => 7 [m] => 1 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [c] => 0 [m] => 2 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [c] => 0 [m] => 3 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [c] => 0 [m] => 4 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [c] => 13 [m] => 5 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [c] => 1 [m] => 6 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [c] => 7 [m] => 7 ) ) ` Вот после Вашей записи что выходит

Comment: @rjhdby массив `in` `Array ( [m] => 1 [c] => 7 ) Array ( [m] => 2 [c] => 0 ) Array ( [m] => 3 [c] => 0 ) Array ( [m] => 4 [c] => 0 ) Array ( [m] => 5 [c] => 13 ) Array ( [m] => 6 [c] => 1 ) ` массив `out` `Array ( [0] => Array ( [m] => 1 [c] => 7 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [m] => 2 [c] => 0 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [m] => 3 [c] => 0 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [m] => 4 [c] => 0 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [m] => 5 [c] => 1 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [m] => 6 [c] => 1 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [m] => 7 [c] => 7 ) )`

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще один вариант на `php`

```
<?php
    $arr = array(
        array('c' => 7, 'm' => 1),
        array('c' => 0, 'm' => 2),
        array('c' => 0, 'm' => 3),
        array('c' => 0, 'm' => 4),
        array('c' => 13, 'm' => 5),
        array('c' => 1, 'm' => 6),
        array('c' => 7, 'm' => 7),
    );

    usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
        return $b['c'] - $a['c'];
    });
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arr);
?>
```